# Automated Trading Buy on Trading View

Tags: pine-script

I'm using the MOMO strategy on TradingView by Matt De Long and I'm wanting to automate trades. I have my Gemini account linked to my tradingview account.

Based on the MOMO Code, how do I automate a Buy or Sell based on the Alerts I receive?

(Exit Long / Enter Short = Sell)
(Exit Short / Enter Long = Buy)

Will I have to create new code for each time Frame? In this case I want to only use the 1 hour charts.

I've copied the MOMO Code Below:

```
//@version=4
//author = https://www.tradingview.com/u/MattDeLong/

study("Trend Following MOMO", overlay=true)
//lh3On = input(title="Buy/Long Signal", type=input.bool, defval=true)
//hl3On = input(title="Sell/Short Signal", type=input.bool, defval=true)
lh3On = true
hl3On = true
emaOn = input(title="105ema / 30min", type=input.bool, defval=true)
assistantOn = input(title="Assistant", type=input.bool, defval=true)
textOn = input(title="Text", type=input.bool, defval=true)

threeHigherLows() =>
    low[0] >= low[1] and low[1] >= low[2]

threeLowerHighs() =>
    high[2] >= high[1] and high[1] >= high[0]

breakHigher() =>
    padding = timeframe.isintraday ? .02 : .1
    high >= high[1] + padding

breakLower() =>
    padding = timeframe.isintraday ? .02 : .1
    low <= low[1] - padding

lh3 = threeLowerHighs() and lh3On
lh3bh = lh3[1] and breakHigher() and lh3On

hl3 = threeHigherLows() and hl3On
hl3bl = hl3[1] and breakLower() and hl3On

ema8 = ema(close, 8)
ema21 = ema(close, 21)

isUptrend = ema8 >= ema21
isDowntrend = ema8 <= ema21
trendChanging = cross(ema8,ema21)

buySignal = lh3bh and lh3[2] and lh3[3] and isUptrend and timeframe.isintraday
sellSignal = hl3bl and hl3[2] and hl3[3] and isDowntrend and timeframe.isintraday

goingDown = hl3 and isDowntrend and timeframe.isintraday
goingUp = lh3 and isUptrend and timeframe.isintraday

//plotshape(goingDown and goingDown[1], style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, size=size.tiny)
//plotshape(goingUp and goingUp[1], style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.tiny)

plotshape(lh3, style=shape.circle, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, size=size.auto)
plotshape(hl3, style=shape.circle, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.auto)
plotshape(trendChanging and isUptrend and assistantOn, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.small, text='Exit Short\nEnter Long')
plotshape(trendChanging and isDowntrend and assistantOn, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, size=size.small, text='Exit Long\nEnter Short')
plotchar(trendChanging and isUptrend and close<open and assistantOn, char='!', location=location.abovebar, color=color.green, size=size.small)
//plotchar(trendChanging and isDowntrend and open<close and assistantOn, char='!', location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, size=size.small)


//RLT 105ema / 30-min chart
ema105 = security(syminfo.tickerid, '30', ema(close, 105))
ema205 = security(syminfo.tickerid, '30', ema(close, 20))
plot(emaOn ? ema105 : na, linewidth=4, color=color.purple, editable=true)
plot(emaOn ? ema205 : na, linewidth=2, color=color.purple, editable=true)

aa = plot(ema8, linewidth=3, color=color.green, editable=true)
bb = plot(ema21,linewidth=3, color=color.red, editable=true)
fill(aa, bb, color=isUptrend ? color.green : color.red)
buyZone =  isUptrend and lh3 and high < ema21 and timeframe.isintraday
sellZone = isDowntrend and hl3 and low > ema21 and timeframe.isintraday


// === ALERT === 

alertcondition(trendChanging, title="Trend Reversing", message="Trend Changing")
alertcondition(buyZone, title="Bullish Trend Following", message="BUY Zone, Perfect")
alertcondition(sellZone, title="Bearish Trend Following", message="SELL Zone, Perfect")
alertcondition(buySignal, title="Long Alert", message="Long")
alertcondition(sellSignal, title="Short Alert", message="Short")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want this to run on 1 hour use the code below and deploy it on chart with timeframe of 1 hour

I have changed
`security(syminfo.tickerid, "30", ....)` to `security(syminfo.tickerid, "60",...`

I am doing the same for the code above. Hope it helps. Feel free to ask for help if it doesn't work

```
//@version=4
//author = https://www.tradingview.com/u/MattDeLong/

study("Trend Following MOMO", overlay=true)
//lh3On = input(title="Buy/Long Signal", type=input.bool, defval=true)
//hl3On = input(title="Sell/Short Signal", type=input.bool, defval=true)
lh3On = true
hl3On = true
emaOn = input(title="105ema / 60 min", type=input.bool, defval=true)   //Change made here, this doesn't have impact on code, just the input screen
assistantOn = input(title="Assistant", type=input.bool, defval=true)
textOn = input(title="Text", type=input.bool, defval=true)

threeHigherLows() =>
    low[0] >= low[1] and low[1] >= low[2]

threeLowerHighs() =>
    high[2] >= high[1] and high[1] >= high[0]

breakHigher() =>
    padding = timeframe.isintraday ? .02 : .1
    high >= high[1] + padding

breakLower() =>
    padding = timeframe.isintraday ? .02 : .1
    low <= low[1] - padding

lh3 = threeLowerHighs() and lh3On
lh3bh = lh3[1] and breakHigher() and lh3On

hl3 = threeHigherLows() and hl3On
hl3bl = hl3[1] and breakLower() and hl3On

ema8 = ema(close, 8)
ema21 = ema(close, 21)

isUptrend = ema8 >= ema21
isDowntrend = ema8 <= ema21
trendChanging = cross(ema8,ema21)

buySignal = lh3bh and lh3[2] and lh3[3] and isUptrend and timeframe.isintraday
sellSignal = hl3bl and hl3[2] and hl3[3] and isDowntrend and timeframe.isintraday

goingDown = hl3 and isDowntrend and timeframe.isintraday
goingUp = lh3 and isUptrend and timeframe.isintraday

//plotshape(goingDown and goingDown[1], style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, size=size.tiny)
//plotshape(goingUp and goingUp[1], style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.tiny)

plotshape(lh3, style=shape.circle, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, size=size.auto)
plotshape(hl3, style=shape.circle, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.auto)
plotshape(trendChanging and isUptrend and assistantOn, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.small, text='Exit Short\nEnter Long')
plotshape(trendChanging and isDowntrend and assistantOn, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, size=size.small, text='Exit Long\nEnter Short')
plotchar(trendChanging and isUptrend and close<open and assistantOn, char='!', location=location.abovebar, color=color.green, size=size.small)
//plotchar(trendChanging and isDowntrend and open<close and assistantOn, char='!', location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, size=size.small)


//RLT 105ema / 30-min chart
ema105 = security(syminfo.tickerid, '60', ema(close, 105))       //Change made here
ema205 = security(syminfo.tickerid, '60', ema(close, 20))        //Change made here
plot(emaOn ? ema105 : na, linewidth=4, color=color.purple, editable=true)
plot(emaOn ? ema205 : na, linewidth=2, color=color.purple, editable=true)

aa = plot(ema8, linewidth=3, color=color.green, editable=true)
bb = plot(ema21,linewidth=3, color=color.red, editable=true)
fill(aa, bb, color=isUptrend ? color.green : color.red)
buyZone =  isUptrend and lh3 and high < ema21 and timeframe.isintraday
sellZone = isDowntrend and hl3 and low > ema21 and timeframe.isintraday


// === ALERT === 

alertcondition(trendChanging, title="Trend Reversing", message="Trend Changing")
alertcondition(buyZone, title="Bullish Trend Following", message="BUY Zone, Perfect")
alertcondition(sellZone, title="Bearish Trend Following", message="SELL Zone, Perfect")
alertcondition(buySignal, title="Long Alert", message="Long")
alertcondition(sellSignal, title="Short Alert", message="Short")
```

Comment: Thanks man! So it should place an auto-buy on whatever exchange I have linked?

Comment: I don't think tradingview has listed your regular broker, you'll have to contact your broker and ask him how to use tradingview api. It will either be a webhook or a browser extension. PS: Confirm if the trades are being generated exactly as you want and read about the risks of automated trading

Comment: Tradingview connects to Gemini.